# Pushing number value (in milliseconds) to function via onclick [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, timer, onclick, setinterval, element

I have the countdown function being called by an onclick button and the values 'remaining', 'elements', and 'callback' [a function] in the button.

```
<input onclick="countdown('4800000', ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'], function(){console.log('Finished');})" type="button">
```

When I click the button, the millisecond value 4,800,000 gets pushed to the function like it should and the page displays the 1 hour and 20 minutes it is equal to, but the function never starts counting down.

I tested my if(isNaN(remaining) with a value of letters being pushed to the function and it displayed the console.log it should, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Please ask if you need the HTML or even CSS from this document if it could resolve an issue.

Sorry for the insane note-taking.

```
//countdown is the entire countdown function called in the HTML file
var countdown = function(remaining /*dateinput*/, elements /*days,hours,minutes,seconds*/, callback/*finished*/) { //end, elements, and callback relate to HTML document


var _second = 1000, //defining 1 second as 1000 (milliseconds)
    _minute = _second * 60, //defining minute as second * 60
    _hour = _minute * 60, //defining hour as minute * 60
    _day = _hour * 24, //defining day as hour * 24
    remaining, //time remaining in countdown
    timer, //defining timer as a variable to start interval and return invalid input if no timer


    calculate = function(){ //defining calculate functiels con for counting down
        var data, //defining data
        countdownalert = function(){ //function to alert with audio after countdown ends
            var audio = new Audio('farmalert.mp3');
            audio.play();
        };

    if(isNaN(remaining)){ //if input date (end) is not a number
        console.log("invalid input"); //return invalid input in console.log
        return; //return/end
    }

    // if remaining time is less than or equal to 0 (if clock has ended)
    if (remaining <= 0) {
    //activates audio alert function
    countdownalert();
    //clear timer
    clearInterval(timer);
        //callback for end of countdown
        if (typeof callback === 'function'){ //if callback is defined as a function
            callback(); //then use function callback
        }
    } 
    else { //everything besides not being a number or being less than 0 (ended)
      if(!timer){ //if timer hasn't started 
        timer = setInterval(calculate, _second); //start ticking/counting every second
       }
            data = { //defining array of data 
            'days': Math.floor(remaining / _day), //calc number to display as days
            'hours': Math.floor((remaining % _day) / _hour),//calc number to display as hours
            'minutes': Math.floor ((remaining % _hour) / _minute),// number to display as minutes
            'seconds': Math.floor((remaining % _minute) / _second)//number to display as seconds
            }
        if (elements.length){ //if elements has a length (exists)
            for (x in elements){ //for x in elements (?confused?)
                var x = elements[x]; // defining x as the current elements in countdown
                data[x] = ('00' + data[x]).slice(-2); //all values in double digit (?slice?)
                document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = data[x]; //using in HTML
            }
        }
        }
    };
calculate(); //running calculate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you never updated the remaining value after each iteration. I did renamed the parameter name to `remainder` and assigned it to a new variable `remaining`. This way I can decrease the value without losing the original timer value:

You can find the live working code here: [Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/604193dx/)

```
var countdown = function(remainder /*dateinput*/ , elements /*days,hours,minutes,seconds*/ , callback /*finished*/ ) { //end, elements, and callback relate to HTML document

var _second = 1000, //defining 1 second as 1000 (milliseconds)
    _minute = _second * 60, //defining minute as second * 60
    _hour = _minute * 60, //defining hour as minute * 60
    _day = _hour * 24, //defining day as hour * 24
    remaining, //time remaining in countdown
    timer, //defining timer as a variable to start interval and return invalid input if no timer
    remaining = remainder,


    calculate = function() { //defining calculate functiels con for counting down
        var data, //defining data
            countdownalert = function() { //function to alert with audio after countdown ends
                var audio = new Audio('farmalert.mp3');
                audio.play();
            };

        if (isNaN(remaining)) { //if input date (end) is not a number
            console.log("invalid input"); //return invalid input in console.log
            return; //return/end
        }

        // if remaining time is less than or equal to 0 (if clock has ended)
        if (remaining <= 0) {
            //activates audio alert function
            countdownalert();
            //clear timer
            clearInterval(timer);
            //callback for end of countdown
            if (typeof callback === 'function') { //if callback is defined as a function
                callback(); //then use function callback
            }
        } else { //everything besides not being a number or being less than 0 (ended)
            if (!timer) { //if timer hasn't started 
                timer = setInterval(calculate, _second); //start ticking/counting every second
            }
            data = { //defining array of data 
                'days': Math.floor(remaining / _day), //calc number to display as days
                'hours': Math.floor((remaining % _day) / _hour), //calc number to display as hours
                'minutes': Math.floor((remaining % _hour) / _minute), // number to display as minutes
                'seconds': Math.floor((remaining % _minute) / _second) //number to display as seconds
            }
            if (elements.length) { //if elements has a length (exists)
                for (x in elements) { //for x in elements (?confused?)
                    var x = elements[x]; // defining x as the current elements in countdown
                    data[x] = ('00' + data[x]).slice(-2); //all values in double digit (?slice?)
                    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = data[x]; //using in HTML
                }
            }
            remaining -= _second;
        }
    };
calculate(); //running calculate
```

}

Comment: Thanks fixed the problem!